# How to apply a function to the value $email of get_user_by to override email_exists?

Tags: email, pluggable, function-exists

More precisely questions : How to override `email_exists` via `get_user_by` ?

I have chosen to render unusable/unreadable email adresses from database.

I added a few elements(chars) to email address just after sending email to admin and user (user registration), and then I must remove these added elements to verify if email exists or display on user account or use for mailing list.

To decrypt the email I must use `substr` whith the value associated to `$email` field of `get_user_by` to remove elements added before.
I read that `email_exists` use `get_user_by` which is a pluggable function. But I don't know how to use the result of `get_user_by` inside `email_exists`.

Is it possible ? How should I do ?

```
        function get_user_by( $field, $db_email ) {
            $field = 'email';
            //function to decrypt my email from database
            $ex = preg_split('\'@\'', $nr , -1);
            $dem = substr(substr($ex[0],2),0,-2);
            $rdem = substr($dem,0,2).substr($dem,2+1,strlen($dem)-2);
            $db_email = $rdem. '@' .$ex[1];
            
            $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( 'email', $db_email );

            if ( ! $userdata ) {
                return false;
            }

            $user = new WP_User;
            $user->init( $userdata );

        return $user;
        }
        
        function email_exists( $email ) {
            $user = get_user_by( $field, $db_email );
            if ( $user ) {
                $user_id = $user->ID;
            } else {
                $user_id = false;
            }
            return apply_filters( 'email_exists', $user_id, $email );
        }
        
        if (email_exists($email)){
            lq_errors()->add("emailexists","This email address already exist");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think the problem may have been that you were checking a variable that was undefined.  You were checking `$db_email`, which in your function was an undefined value, so you'd be looking for an empty result.  You need to check the value passed to `email_exists()` (which would be the email being validated in the form).

If the patterns applied in your pluggable `get_user_by()` function result in the equivalent of how you are obfuscating the emails, then you should get a correct match if the email exists.

```
function email_exists( $email ) {
    // You had this as checking $db_email, which would have been
    // undefined. It should be checking for the value passed to
    // this function - $email.
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
    if ( $user ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    } else {
        $user_id = false;
    }
    return apply_filters( 'email_exists', $user_id, $email );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. How I distinguish the $email variable from the value of the $email field in the database corresponding to the user id. How I apply `preg_replace` on $email field from database before comparing it with $email value inside Form ? In developper.wordpress `get_user_by` from  `email_exists` function use the field 'email' but I can't use it to apply a function ! In your response butlerblog , does $email from `my_custom_email_exists` function get the field $email from database ?

Comment: I would have to hook get_user_by to apply the `preg_replace` function to `email_exists`. But I don't know how. How can I use or insert `get_user_by` inside `email_exists`? Or how do I force `email_exists` to use a custom `get_user_by`?

Comment: Actually, with the edit to your question, I better see how you are using `get_user_by()` as a pluggable function. That's probably better than filtering because it covers every instance of `get_user_by()` when it's getting the user by email.  I've edited my answer above to shift gears and hopefully clarify.

Comment: thanks to help me butlerblog.But Inever know which $email variable I must use to apply my `substr` function.For me, the $email var is the same for input $email and the value corresponding to $email field from database! That's why I would use another var $db_email.I think I don't understand what`email_exists`  do ! I thought that `get_user_by('email', $email)` loop on email values in database, am I wrong? As I tried to explain previously I want to convert on the fly( or apply a filter to) values of the email field from database with substr. one example : in database I have e1xampleta@email.com.

Comment: During the process of email_exists function the email value must return example@email.com. It is this result that I want to compare to the input field filled by another user to verify if the email already exist.

Comment: "During the process of email_exists function the email value must return example@email.com" -- that's not what `email_exists()` returns.  It returns a user ID or false.  "I think I don't understand whatemail_exists do !"  --  The function accepts a value for checking to see if a user exists in the database that already has that email address.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. But does that mean it isn't allowed to render unusable an email address inside database and after verify if email exist or not ? Do you have an idea how I can protect email address of users if a hacker would access to my database ? Does it exist a solution in 2021 to encrypt and decrypt an email address? I read in many answers (stack Wp) that it's not possible (2018 and 2019)